# How find name who send me subscribe request on xmpp using strophe

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, strophe, jabberd2

I am connected to openfire(XMPP) server via Strophe. 
When one user example- "sat" ask for subscription request to another user "sat1". The request and response conversion is as follows.

**"sat" request to "sat1":-**

```
<body rid="1804705405" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" sid="6npq0es11r">
<presence to="sat1@canopus30" type="subscribe" xmlns="jabber:client"></presence>
</body>
```

**Server Response**

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" ack="1804705405">
<iq id="915-56" type="set" to="sat@canopus30/6npq0es11r" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
<item jid="sat1@canopus30" ask="subscribe" subscription="none"></item>
</query>
</iq>
</body>
```

**ON Other Side "sat1" received response from server when connected.**

**Server Response**

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" ack="1602104745">
<presence to="sat1@canopus30" type="subscribe" from="sat@canopus30" xmlns="jabber:client">
</presence>
</body>
```

**"sat1" send subscribe message to user "sat"**

**Request**

```
<body rid="1602104746" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" sid="74ijxeuw0">
<presence to="sat@canopus30" type="subscribed" xmlns="jabber:client"></presence>
<iq id="1" from="sat1@canopus30/74ijxeuw0" type="get" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query>
</iq>
</body>
```

**Server Response**

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" ack="1602104746">
<iq id="73-58" type="set" to="sat1@canopus30/74ijxeuw0" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
<item jid="sat@canopus30" subscription="from"></item>
</query>
</iq>
</body>
```

In above case i cant the full name of user who send the request and who receive the request. Only i have find full JID of both user-end. I want to show the user information on receive and send request.

Many of the tutorials i have seen that i can get the user information on roster but in user information not available on roster also.

**Request**

```
Request :- <body rid="404208005" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" sid="5cou8tu8ka">
<iq id="1" from="sat@canopus30/5cou8tu8ka" type="get" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query>
</iq>
</body>
```

**Server Response**

```
<body xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" ack="404208005">
<iq id="1" type="result" to="sat@canopus30/5cou8tu8ka" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster">
<item jid="sat1@canopus30" subscription="to"></item>
</query>
</iq>
</body>
```

You can see their is not user information in any request and response.
Please help me to find user information on receiving request atleast full name which i given on the user creation(registration).
Thank you.